# Join Column with EmbeddedId, Spring

Tags: java, spring, join

I have following database relations. person_race and race are important in my question.
[image]

I have a problem with creating relationship between race and person_race. What kind of Join should I use?

**PersonRace.java**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PersonRace {


    @EmbeddedId
    @NotNull
    private PersonRaceId personRaceId;

    @Column(name = "player_class")
    @NotNull
    private String playerClass;

    @Column(name = "motorbike_model")
    @NotNull
    private String motorbikeModel;

    @NotNull
    private boolean confirmed;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number_in_race")
    private long numberInRace;
}
```

**PersonRaceId**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonRaceId implements Serializable {

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "race_id")
        @NotNull
        private Race race;
        @OneToOne
        @NotNull
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
        private Person person;
}
```

**Race.java**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Race {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "race_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "max_players")
    @NotNull
    private Integer maxPlayers;
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String location;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @NotNull
    private String state;
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private RaceEvent raceEvent;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "lap_id")
    private List<Lap> laps;
    @OneToMany
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC CODE
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "race_id", referencedColumnName = "race_id"),
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    })
    private List<PersonRace> personRaces;

    public Race(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull Integer maxPlayers, @NotNull String description, @NotNull String location, @NotNull LocalDateTime date, @NotNull String state, @NotNull RaceEvent raceEvent, List<Lap> laps, List<PersonRace> personRaces) {
        this.id = id;
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
        this.date = date;
        this.state = state;
        this.raceEvent = raceEvent;
        this.laps = laps;
        this.personRaces = personRaces;
    }
}
```

I created an controller with findAll function but it doesn't work. It showes error: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "race_person_races" does not exist

**RaceRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface RaceRepository extends CrudRepository<Race, Long> {
    List<Race> findAll();

}
```

**RaceController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RaceController {
    private final RaceRepository raceRepository;

    public RaceController(RaceRepository raceRepository) {
        this.raceRepository = raceRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/races")
    public List<Race> getRaces(){
        return raceRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: You do know, do you not, that you can get a composite PK for an entity simply by annotating multiple fields with `@Id`?  You do not need to create an `@EmbeddedId` for that purpose.  Including when they are relationship fields.  Pulling yours up into the main `PersonRace` entity might clarify to you what the multiplicity of the relationships needs to be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The part of the code you're reffering to was written by someone else, but thank you for your suggestion, I will pass it on to my colleague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague didn't want to change the EmbeddedId like suggested but we solved a problem different way

**PersonRaceId**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonRaceId implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "race_id")
        @NotNull
        @JsonIgnore
        private Race race;
        @ManyToOne
        @NotNull
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
        private Person person;
}
```

**Race.java**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Race {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "race_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "max_players")
    @NotNull
    private Integer maxPlayers;
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String location;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @NotNull
    private String state;
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private RaceEvent raceEvent;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "lap_id")
    private List<Lap> laps;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personRaceId.race")
    private List<PersonRace> personRaces;


    public Race(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull Integer maxPlayers, @NotNull String description, @NotNull String location, @NotNull LocalDateTime date, @NotNull String state, @NotNull RaceEvent raceEvent, List<Lap> laps) {
        this.id = id;
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
        this.date = date;
        this.state = state;
        this.raceEvent = raceEvent;
        this.laps = laps;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your ER diagram, `PersonRace` has a many-to-one relationship with `Race` (and another with `Person`).  That is not correctly reflected on `PersonRaceId`, which in addition to being a problem in itself, leaves the `Race.personRaces` without a viable owning side.  That's probably why JPA is looking for a table named `race_person_races`.

Your `@EmbeddedId` seems to be complicating the matters and confusing you, without serving any useful purpose that I can discern, so I recommend getting rid of it.  That would leave you with:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PersonRace {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "race_id")
    private Race race;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Race {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "race_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "race")
    private List<PersonRace> personRaces;

    // ...
}
```

Note that using the `mappedBy` attribute of the `@OneToMany` enables JPA to figure out for itself the appropriate join column(s).  I don't think you can do that correctly with annotations alone if you use an `@EmbeddedId`.  And as a side note, there is only one join column for this relationship: `person_race.race_id`.